# Auto generating time interval records

Tags: sql, oracle, date, intervals, recursive-query

I have the following table definition and INSERT statement, which work fine.

```
create table.    tour_detail (
  location_id NUMBER(4),
  time interval day to second
  )

insert into tour_detail.    
(location_id,time)
 values (3, interval '11:30' hour to minute)
```

Can the CTE in your example below be modified the tour_detail table to do the following.

- Modify it to leave only HH24:MI set and the rest of the fields = 0.
- How can the times be based on each other like val = val + rand(6,12) minutes.
- If val >= 23:45 can it be reset to some random HH24:MI.
- can a random number (15-25) of tour_detail rows be generated for each tour_hdr(tour_id). When generating these rows only use locations ID rows where location_type = 'G'
- need to ensure the same location_id are not consecutive

I am currently, keeping the tour_detail (tour_time) in
MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS and I only need HH:SS.

```
 ALTER SESSION SET.  NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';



CREATE TABLE locations AS
SELECT level AS location_id,
   'Door ' || level AS location_name,

CASE.    round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'T' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'G' 
     END AS location_type

FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 25;


ALTER TABLE locations 
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT location_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (location_id));


CREATE TABLE tour_hdr AS
SELECT level AS tour_id,
   'Tour ' || level AS tour_name
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 15;


 ALTER TABLE tour_hdr
     ADD ( CONSTRAINT tour_hdr_id_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (tour_id));


create table tour_detail 
(
      tour_id NUMBER(4),
      tour_time DATE,
      location_id NUMBER(4)
 )

declare
  v_loc number;      
  v_prev_loc number := 0;
  v_dt date := trunc(sysdate);
  v_dt_save date := trunc(sysdate);
begin

 for trs in ( select tour_id  from tour_hdr)
  loop

   -- for each  tour generate 15 to 25 rows
    for i in 1..dbms_random.value(15, 25) loop
   
    
   -- If date >23:45:00 reset. Should I
  -- interval be used instead of date

   IF v_dt > (v_dt_save + (1/1440*1425))
   THEN 
   
      -- reset time 
        v_dt :=  v_dt_save;

    ELSE

    -- increase last used date by random 6 to 12 minutes
      
   v_dt := v_dt + dbms_random.value(6,12)/(24*60);

   END IF;

 -- get random location
  select location_id 
    into v_loc 
    from (select location_id from locations where location_type = 'G' order by dbms_random.value) 
    where rownum = 1;

   IF v_prev_loc != v_loc
   THEN
        insert into tour_detail (tour_id, tour_time, location_id)
       values (trs.tour_id, v_dt, v_loc);
       v_prev_loc := v_loc;
    END IF;

  end loop;
 end loop;
end;
```

My goal is to extract a record from tour_detail and find a record for the access_history table and see if the guard was in time, early, late, didn't make the round for that location. In short, I will need to compare a MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS  to a time interval row. Would that be difficult to accomplish

Comment: Should all records have the same `location`?

Comment: No I gave more details in another comment. Wish comments could allow more text. This is hard to communicate this way. Thanks for your patience and expertise

Answer (score 1):

It is not *that* clear which result you actually want, and whether the `location_id` should be fixed or random (if so, how?).

If you are looking to generate a given number of rows with random interval values, then an option is to use a recursive cte and `dbms_random.value`. You need to decide a maximum length for the interval, and a number of iterations. For example, this gives you 10 records with intervals up to 12 hours:

```
with cte(rnd, n) as (
    select dbms_random.value, 1 from dual
    union all
    select dbms_random.value, n+ 1 from cte where n < 10
)
select 3 as location_id, rnd * 12 * interval '1' hour as time
from cte order by n
```

You can turn this to an `insert` statement by just adding the following line at the very beginning of the query:

```
insert into tour_detail (location_id, time)
with ...
select ...
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a3b0cf2e41d69fd2f78eae5980debf5)**:

```
LOCATION_ID | TIME               
----------: | :------------------
          3 | +00 07:13:32.262069
          3 | +00 03:45:18.965145
          3 | +00 07:13:41.394986
          3 | +00 02:24:19.516714
          3 | +00 11:38:16.000109
          3 | +00 11:11:47.947329
          3 | +00 08:14:54.641965
          3 | +00 02:52:43.090595
          3 | +00 03:44:26.418538
          3 | +00 09:29:35.390110
```

Comment: It would be good to include these details in your question, Not everyone is going to find them down here in the comments.

Comment: Clarified my original post. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @GMB your fiddle looks great but I have a few questions. How can the code be changed to leave only HH24:MI set and the rest of the fields = 0. Secondly, how can the times be based on each other like val = val + rand(6,12) minutes. Third, If val >= 23:45 can it be rest to some random HH24:MI. Thanks for your expertise and patience